# Audio support from result

Tags: bixby

How I can make computed-input from javascript response? 
So just choose ONE sound from response ??? I dont want that user will choose some - he will say play sound - Im getting sounds by api call and they start playing

For example I have javascript function:

```
module.exports.function = function CommandContext(userInput, $vivContext){
  return {
    audioInfo: {
        category: 'SINGLE',
        displayName: res.audio.name,
        repeatMode: 'ALL',
        doNotWaitForTTS: true,
        audioItem: [{...}]
    }
  };
}
```

Action Model:

```js
action  (CommandContext) {
  description ('Context')
  type(Search)
  collect {
    input (userInput) {
      type (commandUser)
    }
    computed-input (sound) {
      type (audioPlayer.Result)
      compute {
        intent {
          goal: audioPlayer.PlayAudio
          value: CommandResult.audioInfo
        }
      }
      hidden
     }    
  }
  output (CommandResult)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate some details in the actual utterance? For example, utterance "play Beatles" will result a search and a list of songs returned by API, it normally would be a follow-up dialog, "I found these Beatles songs on XYZ, which one do you want to play?" And it is a single cardinality selection. Is this the case?

Comment: Im just already returning some ONE result from API
on API side Im making decision what to search - so you can say "play bwah" but I will return some default ONE value! 
I dont need to select from user :)

Comment: 1. Ok, so seems by demo https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection/tree/master/audio I can make call to get some audio list with one or more audios on some phrase like "play bethoven" and model trained CANT catch any value in NL by that scheme input - because its audioInfo input? So I have only possibility to use some static actions depending of each sound name?


2. Also if I return this audioInfo - result_view is not working at all?


3. How I can check with emu or real device is that working?

Comment: please see updated answer below

Comment: Ok, I tried result_view with your demo and created new additional files to catch view - https://pastebin.com/abVvYaGT

Its not showing view, just seems audio ( I dont have device yet) - https://pasteboard.co/IbKtH0e.png

Can you check please?

Comment: When sharing code, please share a public repo or zip file so that we can properly run your project.

Comment: Added 4, 5 to the answer below. Basically audioPlayer will halt in simulator and that's why you don't see the result-view.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear you solved it on the API side.

Here are some extra info that might be useful:

- Bixby also can "make decision for user" with `default-select` although it must be either `select-first` or `select-min`, you can read more [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/action.collect.input-group.default-select).
- If in the future you need to implement user selection, or some interactive activity with user after a search, you can try `followup` or `conversation-divers` child key inside `result-view`. Check our reference page [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view).

Let us know if it helps, and have fun with Bixby!

Here are answers to the additional question in comments:

1. That demo is only for play **Meow** as you can see in the JS file. The purpose of the demo is show how to use bixby.audioPlayer library. In actual capsule you should be able to find audio files through API calls according user NL input and turn that into a proper audioInfo structure.
2. result-view should work because still in Bixby.
3. You can definitely test on device after private submissions.

   - How to do [private submission](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/deploying.can-submission)
   - How to [load private submission into device](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/testing.on-device)
4. Since audioPlayer feature currently is not supported in the simulator, running the utterance in simulator will result "pending input" in debug window. The team is reviewing now to see if possible to add the audioPlayer feature in upcoming releases.
5. Thus to test example.meow, you need to do private submission, then upload to device. You need to change the capsule name as well, since it might not allow `example` namespace when you do private submission.

Comment: I tested via emu and entered "Meow" message - got just empty screen and no audio.
How I can see somewhere in logs what happening?

also, why not working double from-ouput ?

  match: CommandResult (commandResult) {
    from-output: CommandContext
    from-output: PlayContext
  }

Comment: Yes, you are correct, on simulator Meow does not result a sound, it need to be on device testing as the audioPlayer is not included in simulator. Please do the following: 1. Do private submission on downloaded example.meow capsule. 2. Load the submission on a Bixby enable device such as S9 phone. 3. Do device testing on the utterance. Sorry, there is no easy way to test the audioPlayer feature except load into device. I will add some link in the answer.